# Update a feature class from a feature class in another geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, feature-class, update

I have a feature class that I update occasionally. Most of the time it is just adding new features, but sometimes I do update attributes on existing features. However, I need to update a 'copy' of this feature class within another database. I have previously just deleted the feature class in the second database and remake it with the updated first feature class. My vendor would like me not to do this.

Is there another way of updating a feature class within a separate database?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3

Answer (score 2):

A solution to update a geodatabase is synchronizing and replication.

**Synchronizes** updates between two replica geodatabases in a direction specified by the user.

**Geodatabase replication** allows you to create copies of data across two or more geodatabases such that changes to the data may be synchronized.

[Synchronize Changes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/synchronize-changes.htm)

[Replicas and geodatabases](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/replicas-and-geodatabases.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of "updating a feature class within a separate [geo]database".

For example, you could provide them with an ArcPy script that includes [Update](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) and [Insert](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) cursors that change, delete and/or update attributes/geometry/both.

They would run this script and perform the updates that you have specified within it.